# Meaning of "D1 q3w" in a poster to a clinical trial

Tags: terminology, clinical-study

From a poster to a [clinical trial](https://ascopubs.org/doi/abs/10.1200/JCO.2020.38.15_suppl.9014):

> [image]

I can understand that **q3w** means "once every 3 weeks", but what is the meaning of **D1**? I think the first **DI** must be a typo and it stands for **D1** too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D1 means on day one of the three weekly cycles. DI is a typo.

https://oncologypro.esmo.org/meeting-resources/esmo-2016/Lurbinectedin-PM01183-administered-once-D1-every-3-weeks-q3w-in-combination-with-capecitabine-XEL-in-patients-pts-with-metastatic-breast-MBC-colorectal-CRC-or-pancreatic-PaC-cancer

Answer (score 1):

DI stands for [diachronic](https://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=2977):

> Diachronic: Over a period of time. The opposite of synchronic.

This would indicate that the medication is given in a drip, not as a bolus.

D1 seems to not have any standard meaning, the conclusion this answerer draws is that D1 is a probable transcription substitution for DI.